# map iterator: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I get this compilation error:

> error: invalid type argument of unary '`*`' (have '`int`')
>       `_M_insert_unique_(end(), *__first);`

I've tried using `(*cols_it).first` and `(*cols_it).second` and every other permutation I can think of, but I can't make it compile.  What should I be writing?

Here's some of the code:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using std::map;
using std::vector;    

void setZeroes(vector<vector<int> > &A) {
    map<int,int> rows;
    map<int,int> cols;
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < A[0].size(); x++) {
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < A.size(); y++) {
            if (A[x][y] == 0) {
                rows.insert(y,y); // error reported here
                cols.insert(x,x);
            }
        }
    }
    map<int,int>::iterator rows_it = rows.begin();
    map<int,int>::iterator cols_it = cols.begin();
    while (rows_it != rows.end()) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < A[0].size(); i++) {
            int val = rows_it->second;
            A[val][i] = 0;
        }
        rows_it++;
    }
    while (cols_it != cols.end()) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            int val = cols_it->second;
            A[i][val] = 0;
        }
        cols_it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, maybe you'd rather use std::set than store pairs of form "x -> x" in the map?

Answer (score 9):

`rows.insert(y,y);` and `cols.insert(x,x);` won't work, [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) expects [`std::pair<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) as its argument.

You could:

```
rows.insert(std::make_pair(y,y));
cols.insert(std::make_pair(x,x));
```

or use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11):

```
rows.insert({y,y});
cols.insert({x,x});
```

or use [std::map::emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) (since C++11) instead:

```
rows.emplace(y,y);
cols.emplace(x,x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix, since you are using `std::map`, is to replace the general container insert:

```
            rows.insert(y,y);
            cols.insert(x,x);
```

with the more convenient indexer of `std::map`:

```
            rows[y] = y;
            cols[x] = x;
```

---

Some of your loop counters look a bit odd, particularly the use of `A[0]` as a substitute of a particular row of `A`.  That can be tidied up, and you could use `std::set` more easily than `std::map`:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

void setZeroes(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &A) {
    std::set<unsigned int> rows, cols;

    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < A.size(); x++) {
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < A[x].size(); y++) {
            if (A[x][y] == 0) {
                rows.insert(y);
                cols.insert(x);
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto r: rows) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < A[r].size(); i++) {
            A[r][i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (auto c: cols) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            A[i][c] = 0; // DANGER: should check c < A[i].size()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `std::map::insert` has different behavior with `std::map::operator[]` when there's already an elment with an equivalent key.

Comment: @songyuanyao - Agreed; my answer is taking advantage of the algorithm never changing an existing value (and for which a set is more appropriate - I've edited).